# html2canvas won't render content of iframe in same domain

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, iframe, html2canvas

**TLDR: I want to open the current page the user is in inside of an iframe, forcing said iframe resolution to be 1920x1080 even in a phone screen, and take a screenshot of said iframe using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), but the image renders as a white image. Since it's the same domain there shouldn't be any issues, but the problem is there.**

Full context:
I have a webpage made with Bootstrap that behaves differently (and correctly) depending on the screen size. However, I've been asked, for the sake of making some reporting tasks easier, to be able to **force** the website to render the way it renders in a 1920X1080 screen when opening it horizontally in a phone screen and requesting the Desktop version (the main idea behind that request is to make the whole application fit into the screen with no scroll, so people in charge of taking screenshots can capture the state of the page in a single image, hopefully with the same aspect than when it renders in a big, computer screen).

I've read solutions suggesting adding this line

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
```

To the HTML headers instead of the usual `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` and that works partially, since it allows the user to take a screenshot capturing the whole page in one image (vertically at least, although I've been requested to make it so it renders horizontally with no scroll as it'd be open).

While studying more approaches, I made it to [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), and the way it works made me think: I'm going to reopen the current page (`localhost/index.html`) into an `iframe`, force said iframe to be 1920x1080 and take a screenshot of said iframe. However, it renders as a white image.

This is the code

```
<iframe id="iframeId" src="index.html" frameborder="0" width="1920" height="1080" ></iframe>
<script>
     const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
     var htmlDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
     console.log(htmlDocument.body);
     html2canvas(htmlDocument.body).then(function(canvas) {
        const base64image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        //window.location.href = base64image;
     });

</script>
```

The iframe renders correctly visually, but the moment the `window.location.href` is done, the iframe renders as a white image. I tried a different approach I found on the internet that opens a Blob instead in a different tab, and it is interesting to notice that the iframe goes white the moment the window.open line runs (see snippet below, this runs inside of the `then` callback of `html2canvas()`).

```
function base64ToArrayBuffer(_base64Str) {
    var binaryString = window.atob(_base64Str);
    var binaryLen = binaryString.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
    for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
        var ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
        bytes[i] = ascii;
    }
    return bytes;
}
    
const base64Canvas = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").split(';base64,')[1];
var byte = base64ToArrayBuffer(base64Canvas);
var blob = new Blob([byte], { type: "image/png" });
window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob), "_blank");*/
```